# OpenMP SIMD vectorization on multiple nested loops

Tags: vectorization, openmp, simd

I have loops doing products, and wanted to use vectorization on it with OpenMP SIMD instructions.

I tried something, with a temporary variable to apply the reduction, but didn't get any improvement (on the contrary) in terms of time. I was expecting to be faster using vectorization.
Is my vectorization wrong ? Can it be better ?

```
float var0 = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < 30; l++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 30; m++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                #pragma omp simd reduction(+:var0)
                for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                    var0 += filter_0[9 * n + 3 * i + j] * INPUT[i + l][j + m][n];
                }
            }
        }
        l0_o[l * 960 + m * 32 + 0] += var0;
        var0 = 0;
    }
}
```

I also have seen, and tried, something like that

```
float var0 = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < 30; l++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < 30; m++) {
        #pragma omp simd collapse(3) reduction(+:var0)
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
                    var0 += filter_0[9 * n + 3 * i + j] * INPUT[i + l][j + m][n];
                }
            }
        }
        l0_o[l * 960 + m * 32 + 0] += var0;
        var0 = 0;
    }
}
```

But it gave even worse results.

Thanks !

Comment: `filter_0` is not read in a contiguous way. This is mandatory for good performance on mainstream x86 CPUs. Recent CPUs have gather instructions for that but they are quite inefficient. Previous x86 CPUs does not even have gather instruction so the code cannot really use SIMD instructions. Besides, note that a compiler can auto-vectorize a code even when you do not add the OpenMP pragmas. Pragmas are just a hint to help the compiler. They do not enforce it to do something. That being said, I do not expect the compiler to auto-vectorize it.

Comment: Can you transpose your input so it's `INPUT[i + l][n][j + m]`, then the data for j+0..2 is contiguous in both `INPUT` and `filter_0`, so one SIMD vector can get all three values.  (With over-read of a 4th which you'd have to ignore).  You could hopefully sum vertically across some `n` values before doing a horizontal reduction.

Comment: It seems `l0_o` is only written sparsely so you can't store a whole vector of results to it, but if you can get different elements of one vector holding results for different `l` or `m`, you could scatter those elements into the output instead of summing horizontally, or maybe end up with that from transpose+sum of multiple vectors for different `m` values if this is like a convolution?

Comment: @JérômeRichard thank you for your answer, so if I change my filter_0 reading to filter_0[9 * i + 3 * j + n], making it continuous, then the vectorization would work ?

Comment: This will be better but the thing is SIMD register are power of two wide (eg. 4 or 8 on mainstream platforms in this case) so I am not sure the compiler will generate a good code for this since there is only 3 items in this dimension. I guess the solution of peter is a bit better since there is more items in the `m` dimension. This is still not great but better than scalar computations. Note that the order of loops needs to be changed and this assume arrays needs to be transposed first. If arrays cannot be transposed then there is no possible way to vectorize this efficiently.